# Magento Model rewrite does not work

Tags: php, xml, magento, model, overriding

I have problem with model rewriting in Magento. There're two custom modules, in first module's config.xml I rewrote core model

```
<models>
    <callforprice>
        <class>Atwix_CallForPrice_Model</class>
    </callforprice>
    <catalog>
        <rewrite>
            <product>Atwix_CallForPrice_Model_Saleable</product>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog>
</models>
```

also I rewrote core block

```
<blocks>
    <callforprice>
       <class>Atwix_CallForPrice_Block</class>
    </callforprice>
    <catalog>
       <rewrite>
            <product_list>Atwix_CallForPrice_Block_Product_List</product_list>
       </rewrite>
    </catalog>
</blocks>
```

getAddToCartUrl is function that was rewrite, this function changing "add to cart" button's URL. In this module it works fine. But when I created new custom module and called function

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

I didn't got needed button's URL. with Seems to rewrite does not work. Button still has core's URL. I know it because I did parse error in Atwix_CallForPrice_Block_Product_List to make sure, and in first module's case I got error, in another  case all works fine.

Sorry for my english, guys.

Comment: Does the $collection return items of Mage_Catalog_Product or Atwix_CallForPrice_Model_Saleable? That may be the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe you need to rewrite the product collection class as well.

Comment: Thanks guys, I found problem. Cause of problem was in another file. That's my fail.